# Which Layout would I take when I want to fit a form in a window

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have multiple forms and want to use one Window class to view them. Now it happens that all forms have a different size and I don't want to manage all of them so I thought about the 'fit' layout along with a min/max wight/height for the Window.

But that would be to easy, if I have applied `dockedItems` the layout messed up along with error that the `layout failed`. Whatever this error is supposed to tell me... But OK I googled and found out that I need to define a height and a width to make this error go away along with a new special property called: `shrinkWrapDock` which should tell the layout to depend on the size of content.

So again my Question

**Which Layout would I take when I want to auto fit a form in a window while the window has a max-/min-size?**

**Edit**

It don't has to be strictly a form, it is just Ext.window.Window configured with a 'fit' layout which should maintain a min / max size for itself. So a very small item within the window may have unused space while a very large one get scrolbars. All in between the min/max of the window are scalled exactly. 
e.g.

```
// lets say we have a window configured like this
{
    xtype:'window',
    minHeight: 50,
    maxHeight: 500,
    layout: 'fit'
}
```

1. **To small form** -> adding a form with just one `textfield`.

   > Window uses `minHeight: 50` because one field has only a height of ~40 px
2. **Fit within min/max** -> adding a form with 6 `textfield`s.

   > Windows scales to size required by the form ~ 240px
3. **To height form** -> adding a form with 20 `textfield`s

   > Window uses `maxHeight: 500` because 20 field has a height of ~800 px

Comment: Are you trying to submit these 2 forms separately? Or does it matter if they're within the same form but just displayed like 2 separate forms?

Comment: @radtad I edited may question to apply much more detailed information. Please take a look

Comment: @JJR, as far as I know you can't get the behavior you're after using the layout config. Min and max are used when the container is re-sized and not at time of content creation. Size of the window needs to be figured out as you add content.

Answer (score 0):

Use a panel inside window(which has fix max,min ht wdt) as parent container, use flex property for it items i.e your multiple forms
eg :

{
 xtype:'panel',
 itemId:'somePanelId',
 layout :'fit',
 items :[
  {
    xtype :'form',
    flex : 2,
    items [{..}]
  },
  {
    xtype :'form',
    flex : 3,
    items [{..}]
  }
}

Try different combinations of flex for each form as per each form's size. While giving flex consider as fix number say '5' here as outof i.e 2/5 size for form1 and 3/5 (three out of 5) space for form2.